# Elixir Ecto: How to store meta information about a many-to-many relationship

Tags: elixir, ecto

Let's say I have the models `User` and `Organization` and a many-to-many relationship between the two. I now want to add information about the kind of relationship between the two. For example `timestamps` and `position`. How do I go about it and how do I query for this information?

I think the right direction is using a join schema. Following the Ecto docs that would be something like:

```
defmodule UserOrganization do
  use Ecto.Schema

  @primary_key false
  schema "users_organizations" do
    field :position, :string # adding information on the position of the user within the organization
    belongs_to :user, User
    belongs_to :organization, Organization
    timestamps # Added bonus, a join schema will also allow you to set timestamps
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:user_id, :organization_id])
    |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:user_id, :organization_id])
    # Maybe do some counter caching here!
  end
end

defmodule User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "users" do
    many_to_many :organizations, Organization, join_through: UserOrganization
  end
end

defmodule Organization do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "organizations" do
    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: UserOrganization
  end
end

# Then to create the association, pass in the ID's of an existing
# User and Organization to UserOrganization.changeset
changeset = UserOrganization.changeset(%UserOrganization{}, %{user_id: id, organization_id: id})

case Repo.insert(changeset) do
  {:ok, assoc} -> # Assoc was created!
  {:error, changeset} -> # Handle the error
end
```

Now how would I set the `position` when creating a record and how would I  query the `timestamps` and the `position`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the `timestamps` and the `position` of your composite schema you can add a `has_many` relationships on both `User` and `Organization`, like this

```
defmodule Organization do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "organizations" do
    many_to_many :users, User, join_through: UserOrganization
    has_many :user_organizations, UserOrganization
  end
end
```

Then you can `Repo.preload` the relationship `user_organizations` when you retrieve `Organization` and all the attributes of `UserOrganization` will be available to you.

Regarding how to set the `position` you can just add it to the changeset and make sure you allow the parameter on `UserOrganization` schema

```
 def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:user_id, :organization_id, :position])
    |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:user_id, :organization_id])
    # Maybe do some counter caching here!
  end

changeset = UserOrganization.changeset(%UserOrganization{}, %{user_id: id, organization_id: id, position: position})
```

And it should work all nicely for you.